# request animation frame loop

Tags: javascript, requestanimationframe

I came across this code 
https://gist.github.com/joelambert/1002116 and i thought of playing around with it

I tried to create a loop and stop it

```
var tick = 0;
var dor = requestInterval(function(){
  tick++;
   console.log("hi", tick)
  if (tick > 10){

     stop();
  }
},300)

function stop(){ 
  console.log("stop")
     clearRequestInterval(dor);
}
```

But the clearRequestInterval is not clearing the timer. But when i tried to call it from a button's event handler its working. Am I missing something?

I have attached a codepen
http://codepen.io/srajagop/pen/KgbbpR

Comment: The code from that gist is not designed to be allow clearing the interval from within the callback function. Sad, but well. I guess you shouldn't use it anyway. If you want to force a stop, you can throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

@Bergi is right that the example code you tried to use is broken, it doesn't support cancelling the interval timer from within the interval function itself. You can work around that by invoking the `clearRequestInterval` asynchronously:

```
function stop() {
  console.log("stop");
  window.setTimeout(function() {
    clearRequestInterval(dor);
  }, 0);
}
```

Or perhaps better, you could fix the example code not to reschedule itself even if it was cancelled from within the interval function.